# How to search multiple value from table using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch value from table up-to `3-label` using PHP and MySQL. Here is my data:

db_users:

```
id      mobile          category   name          multiple_contact

 1    9937229854        1         ra           8908867678,9090567451

 2    8908867678         1         fa           9090567451,89088979765

 3    9090567451         1         we           8908867578,8908897876

 4    89088979765        2         sa           9090453456,9090897869

 5    8908867578          1        gf           9098909876,9098012345
 6    8908897876          1        fd           9098909876,9098012345
 7    9098909876          1        cu
```

Here I am given `id=1` to search the name from tables whose category is always `1`. Here I need to search up to `3-label` and those are explained below.

**label-1:** As per given id user will search first the `multiple_contact` values. If any of them are part the table and their category id=1 those name will fetch first.Here as per condition the output should be `[{'name':'fa'},{'name':'we'}]`.

**label-2:** Again if `multiple_contact` of root user's `multiple_contact` belongs to `category=1` those will be fetched. As per condition the output should be for `9090567451` its `we`,for `8908867578` its `gf` and for `8908897876` its `fd`. finally output should be `[{'name':'we'},{'name':'gf'},{'name':'fd'}]`.

**lable-3:** Again in the similar way for this label output will be `[{'name':'cu'}]`.

The final output should be like below.

```
[{"label1":[{'name':'fa'},{'name':'we'}],"label2":[{'name':'we'},{'name':'gf'},{'name':'fd'}],"label3":[{'name':'cu'}]}]
```

I need the query to find all above data in above format as per `id=1` up to 3-label not more than that. My main aim is no matter how much data is present inside the table, the performance should be very fast.

Comment: Do you just want a query to perform this, or can i suggest a database structure change?

Comment: @Slytherin : This is my existing Database and i also need to very first search. YOu can also suggest the db change.

Comment: I dont understand your search criteria well enough to form queries for them. Maybe you could reword?

The database structure change i had in mind was an MtoN relation instead of the `multiple_contact` column, because that one would have to be searched with LIKE, and thats expensive

Comment: @Slytherin : I have already explained the 3 labels .Please check.

Comment: Thats what I'm referring to when I say "dont understand well enough" Do you want three queries and combine output with PHP? Do you want one query? If you can, for each query you can't figure out for yourself, show and example input ( what to search for ) and an output example. It's the wording around that baffles me.

Comment: @Slytherin : I think one query will good so performance will be good.

Comment: This old question is probably Too Broad (Needs More Focus). From the official close reasons: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer._